# Photoshop causing other programs not receive ESC key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, adobe-photoshop, amd-catalyst

When I run Photoshop CS4 on Windows 7, other running programs don't receive the ESC key (I noticed in PuTTY and Total Commander's Lister). When I close Photoshop, they start receiving the ESC key again.

- I tried multiple keyboard layouts, no change.
- Photoshop is an out-of-box install, no settings changed
- I exported the list of keybindings from Photoshop (ctrl-alt-shift-k) and ESC isn't used in any combination

Why is this? Is there any way to disable or bypass this so that I could use other programs normally?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Photoshop CS4 and ATI Catalyst Control Center both hook the Escape key. To fix it, use Windows Task Manager to terminate ccc.exe and restart Photoshop.

Comment: Thanks, it does work. This describes both the problem and solution accurately and works without the need to run an external program, therefore I chose it as the accepted answer.

Comment: (when in fact neither of them should mess with the Esc key...)

Comment: I *think* you can leave CCC running, but DISABLE hotkey support in the CCC menus

Comment: Thanks! This solved the problem for me too. Disabling hotkey support in CCC did not work; I just stopped CCC from starting automatically.

Comment: I just ran into the same problem, but with Intel's HD Graphics driver rather than CCC. (My machine uses both NVidia discrete GPU and onboard Intel SandyBridge GPU. Had no probs with NVidia only, but enabling Intel GPU as well made me see this problem when Photoshop was running.) -- To fix it I right-clicked Intel's tray icon, then chose Graphics Options, Hotkeys, Disable; then restarted Photoshop. Many thanks to all for pointing me towards the solution; hope this extra info helps someone else.

Comment: @horatio I disabled hotkeys within the Catalyst Control Center, problem still existed.

Answer (score 10):

**Intel chipset** users should right-click on Intel Graphics **tray icon** and **disable hotkeys**.

Other way to do this (if Intel Graphics tray icon missing):

Control panel → Display → Change display settings → Advanced settings → tab "Intel® Graphics and Media control panel" → button "Graphics Propertries" → Options and Support → Hot Key functionality → uncheck "Enable"

From here http://forums.adobe.com/message/1636488#1636488

Comment: Thank you! I noticed this bug in games and thought Steam was the culprit.

Answer (score 4):

It's a issue with the Photoshop and it happens on other programs too. (It's probably related to some Photoshops plugins) You should be able to use <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> to bypass it.

This issue is fixed in CS5.

You could also try one of these programs from here http://forums.adobe.com/message/1636461#1636461 if you are not happy with the SHIFT-method or upgrading to CS5.

Comment: Thanks. I tried PsEscFix.zip but it doesn't work with my Photoshop CS4 64-bit. I wouldn't want it hanging around all the time, anyway. The shift-ESC workaround is good enough for me until I get CS5 or later.

Comment: Shift+Esc might work in some cases, but usually does not. I mean it might close the odd menu, but programs that expect *ESC* won't respond to *Shift+Esc*.

Comment: The issue still occurred for me in CS5 64-bit, when CCC was also running.

Answer (score 2):

The problem wasn't related to any other software in my case.

This is what helped me (Win 7 Professional **x64**, had no such problem with Win 7 Professional **x86**).

Run CS3 - esc did not work. Run CS3 in compatiblity mode with WinXP SP3 - that solved it, but no drag&drop into photoshop (due to different user rights maybe).

I turned off the compatibility mode and the ESC still works as it should :)

EDIT: not **TRUE** that it wasn't related to any other software. When I was testing it I already had Catalyst Control Center (CCC.exe) shut down from another round of testing. So CCC IS somehow involved in this problem. Simply turning off Keyboard shortcuts in CCC **DID NOT** work I had to shut it down (in my case via the TaskManager, but I guess normal quit would work the same, ie. not leaving some other part of CCC.exe running).

Answer (score 0):

Photoshop CS3 (32-bits) on Windows 7, SP1

Photoshop itself can use <kbd>Esc</kbd>. For example, in open file dialog the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key will cancel/close the dialog.

But any other application such as notepad can not use <kbd>Esc</kbd> key.

At the same time, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd> still opens the task manager.

As a vim user, <kbd>Esc</kbd> is most frequently the key used to get back to normal mode. Inside vim <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> is a workaround to bypass the malfunctioned <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

If you close the Photoshop application, the <kbd>Esc</kbd> hook will be released and works again.

I use hotkey explorer utility to find out which application hooks what key.

[How to Fix Photoshop Breaking the Escape Key in Windows](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/20226/how-to-fix-photoshop-breaking-the-escape-key-in-windows/)

Answer (score 0):

I have Intel HD Graphics. Hotkeys in it was already disabled, but problem still was not solved.

I killed the `igfxHK.exe` process and restarted PS - problem solved.

To keep `igfxHK` from running, go to `C:\Windows\System32` and rename `igfxHK.exe` to `igfxHK_.exe`.

**Edit:**

These steps do not solve the problem completely. It seems after a while the error is resumed. I was unable to install because of what. I thought that because of the disguised computer to sleep and recovery, but it is not.
It looks like it just happens over time. To remove this problem for a while, just turn on and turn off the processing of global hotkeys in some other application, such as AIMP. Then you need to restart the PS.
Now it's helped me.

It looks as if it leads to the restoration processing somewhere. Which then somehow it breaks down.

Windows 7, x64, Photoshop CS 3.

Comment: What is igfxHK.exe, why do you think it was running on the OP's system 5 yrs ago, and why would disabling it solve the problem?

Comment: @fixer1234 igfxHK - IntelGraphicsHotKey, but problem not solved completly. I put computer to sleep and wake up after that. Restarted PS and problem goes now. May be something else conflict with ESC hanlder PS.