# Close the Find/Replace dialog in Notepad++ with a keyboard shortcut?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, focus

When I do a find (not a find all, which closes the dialog) or replace in Notepad++, the focus will remain on the find/replace dialog. If I want to focus on the main window with the text in it, I either have to click or clumsily alt-tab + alt-shift-tab, or to close it I have to click. Is there a keyboard shortcut for closing the find/replace dialog?

I have read [this](https://superuser.com/questions/540609/notepad-close-the-find-replace-dialog) question, but it relates to the opposite situation - his version of Notepad++ was focusing on the main window after a find or replace and he was wanting to revert focus back to the dialog.

I'm on 64-bit Win7 if that makes any difference.

Comment: If you had read [Nate's comment](http://superuser.com/questions/540609/notepad-close-the-find-replace-dialog#comment655072_540609) carefully, it was clear that the loss of focus issue was with an older version of Notepad++. On newer versions the dialog remains focused and Esc closes it, which he mentioned as well.

Comment: @Karan - whoops

Comment: Turns out this is caused by Photoshop. See my answer.

Comment: Running an AHK script with an `Esc::` hotkey can also interfere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> will close the find/replace dialog and return focus to the main window.

Comment: This does not work in the most recent versions.

Comment: @EdCottrell: I just tried the two most recent versions, v6.5.2 and v6.5.3. This method still works in both.

Comment: Actually, I now see I misread the question; I thought OP was asking how to close the Find Results window, not the Find/Replace dialog. You  are correct that `Esc` will close the latter.

Comment: There used to be an option to let the find dialogue auto-hide after the first search.  Is that still around?

Comment: Nope, not anymore. I'm also on Win 7 64-bit. Having to click with your mouse when you're writing code should be outlawed! Or something.

Comment: See my answer for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cause, tested by me, and suddenly the Esc key works in npp :)

[Photoshop causing other programs not receive ESC key](https://superuser.com/questions/211556/photoshop-causing-other-programs-not-receive-esc-key)