# Win 8, Photoshop CS2: escape key not working

Tags: windows-8, keyboard, adobe-photoshop

For some reason, Photoshop is preventing the use of the escape key in other programs. This question is also asked here:

[Photoshop causing other programs not receive ESC key](https://superuser.com/questions/211556/photoshop-causing-other-programs-not-receive-esc-key)

...however the accepted solution isn't helping me as I can't find any ccc.exe to terminate in task manager > processes or services. Also, that question is CS4 whereas I'm CS2.

Can anyone advise?

As soon as I quit Photoshop the escape key works again.

Comment: CCC stands for **Catalyst Control Center**, and it's part of the ATI driver package.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm still no wiser as to where to find it.

Comment: What's the exact graphic card model? Is the computer a laptop?

Comment: GeForce 820M...

Comment: GeForce 820M is a graphic card manufactured by NVIDIA, and that's why you don't have the Catalyst Control Center. The "M" at the end of model name stands for Mobile, hence it's version designed for notebooks. What's the Photoshop CS2 version displayed in the About dialog?

Comment: Version 9.0....

Comment: Just to clarify, you mean the latest version of the free one, right? That's what I'm using - CS2. Not the latest (paid) one.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15059/discussion-between-and31415-and-utkanos).